# Text between pattern match RegEx Python

Tags: python, regex

I need some help with the following pattern, I am struggling many hours now.
I have a text like:

```
<<12/24/2015 00:00  userrrr>>
********** Text all char and symbols ************
<<12/24/2015 00:00 CET userr>>
Text all char and symbols
<<12/24/2015 00:00 GMT+1 userrrr>> Text in same line
<<12/24/2015 00:00 CET userrr>>
Text all characters and symbols
<<12/24/2015 00:00 GMT+1 userrrrrrr>> Text in same line
More Text all characters and symbols
<<12/24/2015 00:00 CET userrrrr>>
More text all characters and symbols
<<12/24/2015 00:00 CET userrrrrrrrrrr>>
More Text all characters and symbols
```

By Using the pattern:

```
(\<<)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?(?=>>))(>>)
```

The datetime and everything between the arrows is matched correctly.Unfortunately,
I can not find a way to extract the text between the patterns.The final groups should look like (left_arrows), (datetime), (user), (right_arrows), (text).The closer I got was by using:

```
(\<<)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\D{3}.*?(?=\s))\s(.*?(?=>>))(>>)((?s).*?(?=<<\d{2}/\d{2}))
```

But it doesn't match the first and the last correctly.[Click Here to check the result(pythex.org)](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5C%3C%3C)(%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F%5Cd%7B4%7D%5Cs%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cs%5CD%7B3%7D.*%3F(%3F%3D%5Cs))%5Cs(.*%3F(%3F%3D%3E%3E))(%3E%3E)((%3Fs).*%3F(%3F%3D%3C%3C%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F%5Cd%7B2%7D))&test_string=%20%20%20%20%3C%3C12%2F24%2F2015%2000%3A00%20%20userrrr%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20**********%20Text%20all%20char%20and%20symbols%20************%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C12%2F24%2F2015%2000%3A00%20CET%20userr%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Text%20all%20char%20and%20symbols%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C12%2F24%2F2015%2000%3A00%20GMT%2B1%20userrrr%3E%3E%20Text%20in%20same%20line%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C12%2F24%2F2015%2000%3A00%20CET%20userrr%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Text%20all%20characters%20and%20symbols%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C12%2F24%2F2015%2000%3A00%20GMT%2B1%20userrrrrrr%3E%3E%20Text%20in%20same%20line%0A%20%20%20%20More%20Text%20all%20characters%20and%20symbols%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C12%2F24%2F2015%2000%3A00%20CET%20userrrrr%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20More%20text%20all%20characters%20and%20symbols%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C12%2F24%2F2015%2000%3A00%20CET%20userrrrrrrrrrr%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20More%20Text%20all%20characters%20and%20symbols&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: what do you want to extract? You sure `line.startswith("<<")` could not do most of what you want?

Comment: 3 groups (datetimeoffset) ,(User),(Text Between pattterns) . So now I am failing to extract the text between patterns. I don't have an issue with the first 2 groups.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `BeautifulSoup`?..

Answer (score 1):

```
(\<<)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\D{0,3}.*?(?=\s))\s(.*?(?=>>))(>>)((?s).*?(?=<<\d{2}/\d{2}|$))
                                                                                                ^^
```

You need to give `|$` for the last line to match.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/51

Comment: Hi vks, the last line works now, thanks for the info.While in your demo works, in my terminal and pythex link the "********** Text all char and symbols ************ " fails .

Comment: @Zars try `(\<<)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\D{0,3}.*?(?=\s))\s(.*?(?=>>))(>>)([\s\S]*?(?=<<\d{2}/\d{2}|$))`

Comment: @vsk no the second one does not work, I am still wondering why in regex101 works , but no in pythex and my terminal...

Comment: @Zars Can u show d code where u r implementing d same

Comment: @vsk Just figured out that the pattern works for `<<12/24/2015 00:00 CET userr>>` but not for `<<12/24/2015 00:00 userrrr>>` where timezone is missing.To see my implementation check the link on my first post.I think I am getting closes,Thanks.

Comment: @vsk Checked it ,I can see that it works ,but it does not work on pythex and the outpout of my script  is the same as in pythex .

Comment: @Zars `(\<<)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\D{0,3}.*?(?=\s))\s(.*?(?=>>))(>>)([\s\S]*?(?=<<\d{2}/\d{2}|$))` this is working for me in my cimplier

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way will be to go over the file line by line and try to match them with different regexes, one for header lines and one for text lines. But if you really need to get it in one shot, you could do:

```
(\<<)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?(?=>>))(>>)\n\*+([^\*]+)\*+\n
```